# Rails Routing Wildcard

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, I am trying to do a wildcard to redirect anything in in /api/foobar/ to go to controller foobar and run method default. I am using `get` right now, but it can be any http method such as `post`, `put`, etc.

I tried:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  get 'foobar*', to: "foobar#default"
end
```

but to no success.

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can work with this setup:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  match '/foobar/*path', to: "foobar#default", via: :all
end
```

You will get your path in `params[:path]` inside controller.

There is a wildcard segment chapter in Rails guides too: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments

**Note** as @dman noted, `via: :all` option works only for Rails 4 and above. For Rails 3 you should use:

```
match '/foobar/*path', to: "foobar#default", via: [:get,:post,:put,:delete]
```

Comment: I don't know why but `:all` will not work. I had to use [:get, :post, :put]. Also, is there a way to get the whole query string included in the path for convenience so I wouldn't have to rebuild the path and query string?

Comment: Use `request.query_string` or `request.query_params`

Comment: I will check `:all` later and send you response

Comment: @dman I tested `via: :all` option (see updates in my answer). I tested in for Rails 4. Which version are you using?

Comment: Rails 3.2.18... I can't find if that `all` was available in that ver or not

Comment: @dman you are right. There is no `all` option in Rails 3. I've updated my answer based on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    match '*path' => 'foobar#default', :via => [:get,:post], :constraints => {:path=> 'foobar.*'}
end
```

I would advice to read up on:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-constraints